# SQL case statement with multiple return values

Tags: sql

Anyone has a hack for something like this? it doesn't need to be a case statement. I don't have access to Union or Join functionality so preferably without using those. But if using Union or Join is the only way to achieve it, then I'm still interest in a solution.

Here's some sample data:

Status table:

```
(value, name):
(1, 'pending'),
(2, 'complete'),
(3, 'incomplete'),
(4, 'not required')
```

Account table:

```
(name, accountNo, statusValue) : 
('Google', 12345, 1),
('Google', 12346, 2),
('Google', 12347, 1),
('Amazon', 22356, 1),
('Amazon', 22357, 3),
('Amazon', 22358, 2),
('Foo', 35677, 4),
('Foo', 35678, 4),
('Foo', 35672, 4)
('Bar', 55555, 1),
('Bar', 55556, 2),
('Bar', 55557, 3)
```

So an Account can have multiple account numbers. Depending on if the account numbers has been processed, it can change from 'pending' to 'complete'. It can be 'not required'  meaning this account doesn't need to be processed at all.

One example is: I want to select the count of each account at the end of the day. If the account is from Amazon, Ebay, Facebook, then I only want to count only the account numbers that have been completed. Otherwise, I want to do a count all the account numbers (or all the account numbers that has not been completed, or only the account numbers that have a certain status).

```
select account, count(account) from AccountTable 
where status = case 
    when account in ('name1', 'name2', 'name3') then (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    else (1, 2, 3) end group by account;
```

or simpler case like this:

```
select name, count(name) from AccountTable 
where statusValue = case 
    when name in ('Amazon', 'Google', 'Ebay') then 1
    else everything     --everything as in all status, not a single value 'everything'
    end group by account;
```

expected output for second select statement:

```
 Name      Count(Name)
 Amazon      1
 Google      2
 Foo         3
 Bar         3
```

and lastly, this:

```
select name, count(name) from AccountTable 
  where status = case 
    when account in ('Google', 'Amazon', 'Ebay') then 1
    else not 1  --every status that is not 1
    end group by account;
```

Thanks (Please ignore syntax errors).

Comment: Case expression, not case statement...

Comment: Can you add some sample table data, and it's expected result?

Comment: Post some sample data and the expected results.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do

Comment: @jarlh updated the question. I hope it's still not as confusing.

Comment: Much better. And it would be even better if you also added the expected result!

Comment: oh I would need real data to get expected data. Let me retry with these datas

Comment: @jarlh ok updated, let me know if I made any mistakes in the output or it is still confused. The ouput is for the middle select statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing what I think you're doing, you can do this with normal Boolean logic.

The first statement is logically equivalent to:

```
select account, count(account) from AccountTable 
where (
        status in (4, 5, 6)
        and account in ('name1', 'name2', 'name3')
    )
    or status in (1, 2, 3)
group by account;
```

Note that `status in (4, 5, 6)` replaces `status in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)` because, again, it's logically equivalent here due to the `or`.

The second statement is logically equivalent to:

```
select account, count(account) from AccountTable 
where (status = 1 and account in ('name1', 'name2', 'name3'))
    or status <> 1
group by account;
```

Comment: I don't have the database to test right now but first statements look correct. However, the 2nd statement would select status (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) for 'name1', 'name2', 'name3' due to the "or status <> 1" and select (2, 3, 4, 5, 6) for others, doesn't it?

Comment: well it doesn't matter. I can reverse the logic to "where status <> 1 and account not in ('name1', 'name2', 'name3')) or status = 1. Thanks!

Comment: @user3758745 Cool.  Just remember that AND is higher precedence than OR so `x = 1 and y = 2 or z = 3` means `(x = 1 and y = 2) or z = 3` and not `x = 1 and (y = 2 or z = 3)`.  When you combine AND and OR together it's best practice to use parentheses to make it unambiguous what you want.